# Adding film-grain to large image (how to make "grains" bigger)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, noise

I am attempting to make a film grain effect over a large image (2000 pixels by 3000 pixels).

I tried using this tutorial - https://medialoot.com/blog/how-to-simulate-film-grain/. The results were very subtle, in that the "grains" that it produced were very small and you couldn't see them on areas that were not light.

I think that the issue is that my image is so big, and the grains produced by the "noise" filter in photoshop is automatically a certain size. I can control the degree of noise on this filter, but not the size of the grains.

To be clear, this is the degree of grainy effect I'm going for http://www.derekabella.com/ - similar to 35 ml film

Answer (score 4):

You could turn your artwork/layers into to a Smart Object, and use Adobe Camera RAW as a filter, then click on the "fx" tab.

This is an example on a large 5792px wide image. I maxxed out all the sliders on the Grain controls, and also added some post-crop vignetting.

[image]

Since it's a filter on a Smart Object, you can readjust it at any time. It's a nice non-destructive way of adding large grains.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that I agree that the images you link to has *larger* grains than you can get with the *Noise* filter. They are just "harsher". A different kind. And I don't think they look like 35 mm film grain (which I would expect to be "softer"), but more like it's mimicking some form of [lithography printing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithography) where the grains come from the texture of the stone used.

Take for example [this image](https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/580e5588f5e231ed3f4f1711/1586803140313-3C3XTQVFIVRUGZ2VZ4Z6/ke17ZwdGBToddI8pDm48kPTrHXgsMrSIMwe6YW3w1AZ7gQa3H78H3Y0txjaiv_0fDoOvxcdMmMKkDsyUqMSsMWxHk725yiiHCCLfrh8O1z4YTzHvnKhyp6Da-NYroOW3ZGjoBKy3azqku80C789l0k5fwC0WRNFJBIXiBeNI5fKTrY37saURwPBw8fO2esROAxn-RKSrlQamlL27g22X2A/breakup1wip.jpg?format=2500w). If you download it, open it in Photoshop and zoom in on the grains, you will discover that they are all 1x1 px size. Not *larger* than the noise produced by the *Noise* filter:

[image]

Furthermore, the noise in the linked image doesn't seem to just be added to the image *as a whole*, but carefully applied to *different parts* of the images in different amounts. Also notice how the noise in the individual parts seem to confine to different "color palettes".

I can't tell for sure how this was done. The artist probably spent a considerable amount of time experimenting with different approaches. But I can try to inspire you to get started experimenting for yourself.

---

I propose a method where you have the individual shapes of your drawing as *Layer Masks* on groups. The shadows and highlights are kept on individual *Solid Color* layers inside the group each with their own layer mask. I tend to just draw with the sharp *Pencil Tool* and add *Feather* to the layer masks, but you could draw with soft brushes instead if you prefer.

Both the group itself and the individual color layers should have the *Blend Mode* called *Dissolved* which renders transparency as completely sharp 1-bit noise.

Here is a quick example showing the principle:

[image]

Using this method you can sort of "paint with noise" and you have complete control over the colors used in the noise.

---

Here is a more complex example with a drawing of a ball or planet using several colors. The *Layers* panel looks like this:

[image]

And the finished drawing looks like this (click on it to see it in its original size):

[image]

This looks a bit like the grain you like, only it consists of very few different colors and looks a bit too sharp. The trick is to work at perhaps double size and then scale down the image in the end. Using *Bicubic Sharper* interpolation is probably best as it smoothens the image, but also keeps the noise relatively sharp.

This is the drawing of the ball scaled down to 50% of its original size:

[image]

You could also convert all your layers to a single *Smart Object* and then scale down the main document to 50% of the original size. That way you see how the finished image looks while maintaining the possibility to enter the smart object and work on the coloring.